# Tab completion and Mobaxterm

Tags: bash, autocomplete, mobaxterm

I am using Mobaxterm to access cluster that is running on Bash. I have an absurd, but very annoying issue.

- When I installed Mobaxterm, <kbd>Tab</kbd> completion would end the path with a `/` and if you press it again, it would list all files and subdirectories in that path.
- I have no idea what happened, but now as soon as I type a directory name, <kbd>Tab</kbd> completion ends with a blank space instead by `/` which is extremely annoying if I wanted to navigate further down the directory tree.

To clarify this issue by an example, let's say I have the following directory structure:

```
src
+-lib1
  +-file.cpp
  +-lib2
```

When I type `nano src/lib1` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> I am expecting autocomplete `src/lib1/`. Hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> again would then list `file.cpp`.

Instead what happens is that I get `src/lib1`  so I have to delete blank space, type `/` manually and only then would things work.

I hope you can imagine how frustrating this is when navigating through loads of directories.

Overall, I want bash to add trailing `/` after each path during autocompletion, any idea how to enable this?

Comment: that's a problem on your Windows frontend, not on the Unix backend.

Comment: A cluster running on bash? That's quite something.